# How does elsif work in Perl?

Tags: perl, conditional-statements

Why does Perl have 'elsif' and not 'elseif'?

I am doing something like this:

```
$somevariable = 0;
if ($idcount==5) 
{
    # Do something
    if (somestatement is true) # 1 
    {
        $somevariable = 1;
    }
}
elsif ($idcount > 1 && somevariable = 0)
{
    # Do something else here
}
```

The code never comes to the elsif statement. In this case `idcount` is actually 5, so it comes to the first if statement. But an inner `if` statement (1) is not true, so `$somevariable` is still 0.  Since `idcount` is 5, it should come to `elsif` as well since `$idcount` is greater than 1 and `$somevariable` is still 0.

Maybe I am just tired and not seeing something obvious.

Comment: Please cut and paste, don't retype.  When you retype, you not only potentially fix your actual problem without noticing it, but you introduce others that then distract people from being able to help you.

Answer (score 12):

No, anything in an `elsif` only has a chance to be executed if none of the previous if/elsif conditions have been true, that's the "else" part of it.

If you want both to be evaluated, just make it an `if` instead of an `elsif`.

Answer (score 11):

```
elsif ($idcount > 1 && somevariable = 0)
```

Should be:

```
elsif ($idcount > 1 && $somevariable == 0)
```

The assignment operator returns the assigned value, 0, which equates to false, thus the logical and '&&' always fails.

Comment: Sure it does.  The bug prevents "elsif" from reaching that code block.  The rest of the code looks ideal.

Comment: No, it's a separate problem. styris was expecting the code to go into the if-block and then come out of there and go into the elsif-block.

Comment: Don't forget the $ in front of somevariable

Answer (score 11):

Here is how [the Llama book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520106/) answers the elsif vs elseif question:

> "Because Larry says so."

Answer (score 7):

In any if-elsif-else construct, you only ever execute the first branch whose condition is true. Once that branch executes, the program picks up after the entire if-elsif-else.

If you want to do something with possible multiple branches, you can construct your own case-like syntax with multiple `if` blocks. There is a `given-when` construct from Perl 5.10 but its has retrograded into experimental status and may be removed from the language.

As for the spelling of `elsif`, there are a couple of factors involved.

In C, you write

```
if( ... ) {
   ... }
else if ( ... ) {
```

That sometimes causes a "dangling else" problem. If you had started but didn't finish inserting an `if-else if` right before another, but distinct, `if`, you've combined the two through the dangling else.  Larry Wall didn't like that, so he combined the 'else if" into one word, "elseif". However, that looked odd to Larry since the rule is "i before e except after c, ...", so he fixed that by taking out the "e" to make it just "elsif".

Comment: Wall's requiring _blocks_ rather than simple statements completely solved the dangling else problem, right? I think the OP's question might have been asking why Wall chose not to make the grammar simply `IfStmt ::= 'if' '(' Exp ')' Block ('else' 'if' '(' Exp ')' Block)* ('else' Block)?` I don't see why that would not have worked, nor why there would be any dangling else issues. Do you have a second to clarify? Are you simply saying there might be a higher chance of a typo?

Comment: You can still forget to add the block for the else and have it run into a different if structure.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That is bit of a stretch, though. Was that really the reason that Wall gave? Would a programmer really write `if (e) {something} else`  and then just stop there and leave some blank lines then follow that with another `if` statement? I'm not seeing that as remotely plausible, but we are talking about Perl, so who knows (SORRY!). My own guess is that Wall did not like the LL(2)-ness of `else if` (`elsif` makes it LL(1)) but if you have first-hand knowledge of Wall's rationale then great answer!

Comment: It was about C. Maybe some code was removed to create the dangling else, or incompletely pasted, or all sorts of other reasons.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see what your confusion has to do with the fact that perl uses "elsif" rather than "else if" or "elseif".  In every language I've ever used, from pre-1970s-style FORTRAN to Java and including along the way such "highlights" as Easytreive, if you do "if cond ... else ..." the stuff after the else doesn't get executed if the original "cond" is true.  That's what "else" means.

In your case, the "cond" is "($idcount==5)", which you already stated is true, and the else part that doesn't get executed because it's true is "if ($idcount > 1 && $somevariable == 0) ...".

Answer (score 3):

Perl has elsif because perl doesn't allow C style "else if" without brackets.  Instead, you would need to have something like:

```
if (x) {

}
else {
  if(y) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"elsif" in Perl works exactly the same as "elseif", "else if", and "elif" in other languages. It's just a matter of spelling.

Answer (score 1):

### Here is the equivalent of what was posted in the question.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$somevariable = 0;
if ($idcount==5) 
{
  # do something
  if ( 1 )
  {
    $somevariable = 1;
  }
}
else
{
  if ($idcount > 1 && somevariable == 0) # this line was wrong in the question
  {
    # do something else here
  }
}
```

#### or

```
use Modern::Perl;

$somevariable = 0;
given($idcount){
  when( 5 ){
    # do something
    if ( 1 ){
      $somevariable = 1;
    }
  }
  when( $_ > 1 && $somevariable == 0 ){
    # do something else here
  }
}
```

`use Modern::Perl;`
is the same as
`use strict;`
`use warnings;`
`use 5.010;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `if...elsif` in any language, your conditions should be mutually exclusive.  The two conditions in your example could both be true simultaneously, so you should break that up into two separate `if` statements.