# Why is a directory listing not working on my Windows system?

Tags: perl

Why is the below code is not working?

`-d` and `-f` are not functioning on my Windows machine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump qw/pp/;

my $path="C:/perl/workspace";
opendir ( DIR, $path ) || die "Error in opening dir $path\n";

my (@file,@dir);

while (my $filename=readdir(DIR)) {
    next if ($filename =~ m/^\./);
    if (-f $filename) {
        push(@file,$filename);
    } elsif (-d $filename){
        push(@dir,$filename);
    }
}

#pp \@file,\@dir;
print "@dir";
```

Comment: Regarding "elsif": [Why does Perl have 'elsif' and not 'elseif'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659553/how-does-elsif-work-in-perl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for file with path,

```
if (-f "$path/$filename")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the $path to the $filename before checking if it's a file or directory as readdir only returns the filenames without the path.

```
 ...
 if (-f $path."/".$filename) {
    push(@file,$filename);
  } elsif (-d $path."/".$filename){
    push(@dir,$filename);
  }
 ...
```